# What does #! mean when showing up multiple times in example python code and not just the first line of a script?

Tags: python

What does #! mean when showing up multiple times in example python code and not just the first line of a script?

Example of how I've found it showing up in some sample code:

```
#! [connectack]
def connectAck(self):
    if self.async:
        self.startApi()
#1 [connectack]
```

What does this code do differently by including the #1 [...] lines?

Comment: No idea; some random tool overloading comments. Perhaps some code generator tracking where functions start and end?

Comment: There is no *Python-specific* meaning to those comments at least. To Python, they are just comments.

Comment: I seen "connectack" with regards to DHCP messages, where it means "connect acknowledgment,"  perhaps that's what this code pertains to?

Answer (score 6):

Those are just Python comments (`#` turns the rest of a line into a comment in Python).

There may be some tools that take advantage of the contents of the comments to do something, but they're not anything standard with Python.

Answer (score 0):

They are comments.

After you start with a # the rest of that line wil be commented and will not effect your code in anyway.

To comment a line can be usefull in the way that you can explain what the following function or code does. To keep track of your code for yourself or for others.

It is very usefull when working in a project group.